# Uniform type mismatch error - OpenGL ES 3.0 shader program linked on Android 7/8/9 but failed on iOS 10/11?

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I was frustrated by an error when linking OpenGL es shader 3.0 program on iOS.

I have one vertex shader and one fragment shader and they are linked to generate a single program. 
There are shared uniforms and uniform blocks in both shaders. I understand that these uniforms must have exactly same type, precision and name, so that I even copy the uniform declaration from one shader to the other shader.

Here is the code of **my vertex shader**:

```
// Vertex shader
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

// ........................... 
// Shared uniforms ...

uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 texcoordMatrix;
uniform mat4 projMatrix;

uniform bool shadingEnabled;
uniform bool fogEnabled;
uniform bool flatShading;
uniform bool specularEnabled;
uniform bool generateReflectionTexCoord;
uniform float zBias;

layout (std140) uniform cbFog
{
    int     g_fogMode;
    float   g_fogStart;
    float   g_fogEnd;
    float   g_fogDensity;
    vec4    g_fogColor;
};
layout (std140) uniform cbMaterial
{
    vec4 mtlAmbient;
    vec4 mtlDiffuse;
    vec4 mtlSpecular;
    vec4 mtlEmissive;
    int  mtlSpecularPower;
    float _padding4;
    float _padding5;
    float _padding6;
};

// ........................... 
// Vertex shader's input and output ...

// ........................... 
// Vertex shader code ...
```

And here is the code of **my fragment shader**:

```
// Fragment shader
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

// ........................... 
// Shared uniforms ...

uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 texcoordMatrix;
uniform mat4 projMatrix;

uniform bool shadingEnabled;
uniform bool fogEnabled;
uniform bool flatShading;
uniform bool specularEnabled;
uniform bool generateReflectionTexCoord;
uniform float zBias;

layout (std140) uniform cbFog
{
    int     g_fogMode;
    float   g_fogStart;
    float   g_fogEnd;
    float   g_fogDensity;
    vec4    g_fogColor;
};
layout (std140) uniform cbMaterial
{
    vec4 mtlAmbient;
    vec4 mtlDiffuse;
    vec4 mtlSpecular;
    vec4 mtlEmissive;
    int  mtlSpecularPower;
    float _padding4;
    float _padding5;
    float _padding6;
};

// ........................... 
// Fragment shader's input and output ...

// ........................... 
// Fragment shader code ...
```

**Please note that all uniform declarations are copied from vertex shader into fragment shader so that they are guaranteed to be identical.**

The result is that the program can be successfully linked on Android and some OpenGL ES simulators like PowerVR, but it fail to be linked on iOS 10/11 and the following is the error message:

```
Error when linking shader program:
ERROR: Uniform type mismatch '<uniform cbMaterial>'
ERROR: Uniform type mismatch '<uniform cbFog>'
```

The iOS OpenGL ES complains that uniform block **cbMaterial** and **cbFog** have *mismatched type*. 
Anyone can help me find the reason for me? Thanks!

*PS: I understand that OpenGL ES might be deprecated on macOS 10.14 and iOS 12, I still need to get this working on iOS for certain maintenance reason.*

Comment: What device are you receiving the error on?

Comment: iPhone 6, iPhone 6 plus and iPad 2018 with iOS 11.2, they all gave me the same error message.

Comment: Have you tried no to use Uniform blocks?, Maybe it is a layout ( std140 ) issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Since my sahders are used for numbers of other platforms, so change uniform blocks into uniforms will cause more maintenance job.